# Removing extreme values from a (calculated) raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, landsat

I have a Landsat GeoTIFF with a multiplicative scaling factor of 0.01.

When I load the tif into QGIS and multiply the raster by 0.01 extreme values are created (see attached picture).

[image]

Looking at the calculated and source layer, it looks kike the extreme values are due to differing CRS between the Landsat and calculated layer:

[image]

I've tried to address this at the calculation stage, but without success.  Equally, I've tried setting values below 0 to 'no data', and a variety of other suggestions found online but I can't get it to behave - none of the raster calc solutions works (normally QGIS says there is formula error and won't proceed).

The Landsat tif used can be downloaded from [here](https://livelancsac-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/monkp_lancaster_ac_uk/ES9BP0pCtJ5DhRwmyv0yZ6oBSuXvD578i03Evr3toHqk3w?e=9RRRMb).

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you say that "I have a Landsat GeoTIFF with a multiplicative scaling factor of 0.01" but, in your picture, you have a landsat 9 product with ID equals to:

```
LC09_L2SP_039035_20220703_20220705_02_T1
```

and, exhibited image (Las Vegas, Nevada), it is for **ST_B10** band. In this case, [for converting values to kelvin](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC09_C02_T1_L2), the multiplicative scaling factor is 0.00341802 and the adding scaling factor is 149. So, conversion formula in raster calculator is as follows:

```
"LC09_L2SP_039035_20220703_20220705_02_T1_ST_B10@1" * 0.00341802 + 149
```

After applying above formula, I got result of following picture. There is not "extreme values" and surface temperature values (Kelvin degrees) are as expected. It can also be observed that there are not colored areas outside image (in your case red areas) reflecting correctly no data values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I suspect I've muddled up my images and process - the effect was a real one.  As I currently have Covid I'm going to blame the virus.  I'll check and update this when I'm better.

Comment: It was partly a projection issue, the Landsat image being in one CRS, and the calculated area in another.  This created areas of no data (see above).  There is also a issue related to distance to cloud and the algorithm used to calculate LST in Landsat Collection 2 Level 2 data products - the uncertainty values manifest strangely (see another post of mine).